# How do I loop one modal into another using JavaScript Recursion and at what point it should stop looping if not given any parameter manually?

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am writing a program to open a Modal Box in the center of the screen. The box fits the screen & occupy 80% of screen width and height. The box has a link to it when clicked will open another Box within its center at 80% size of its outer parent box, and so on (recursion).Now it should stop at a point where its mathematically impossible to fit another box and gives me an alert(can't loop anymore). I have written some code on my own and now, I am stuck. My very two doubts are -

a) when I loop a child box into the parent on click, how do I disable the parent link (because I want on click event to only work on child element)?
b) what would be that one point where my recursion will stop itself and give me an alert?

This is the code I have written so far:

HTML:

`<div class="modal loop-over" id="box"></div>`

CSS:

```
.modal {
   width: 80%;
   height: 80%;
   margin:0 auto;
   display:table;
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right:0;
   cursor: pointer;
   top: 50%; 
   border:1px solid;
   -webkit-transform:translateY(-50%);
   -moz-transform:translateY(-50%);
   -ms-transform:translateY(-50%);
   -o-transform:translateY(-50%);
   transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

Javascript:

```
var loopBtn = document.querySelector('.loop-over');

loopBtn.addEventListener('click', function() {
        appendBoxes();
});

function appendBoxes() {
    var box = document.getElementById('box');
    var clone = box.cloneNode(true);
    box.append(clone);
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

A) To prevent clicks on one element from triggering a click on a parent element, you must stop the click event's propagation:

```
function onClickBox(event) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

I don't think you'll need this, because you are attaching an event handler in a way that will result in only the outer box having a click handler, no matter how many child boxes are subsequently added.

B) The recursion limit is kind of up to you. However, I think it's reasonable to decide that the limit has been reached if the next box would be less than 1px wide or high. This is an arbitrary limitation: mathematically, you can always multiply a value by 0.8 and get a new, smaller value. I chose this limit because the visualization naturally suggests a floor to what would otherwise be an infinite path. You could make that determination by measuring the box that has been clicked and calculating whether either of its edges is so short that `length * 0.8 < 1.0`.

---

It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. I can imagine two possibilities:

1) user clicks, and a single box appears; user clicks a second time, and a second box appears inside the first; one box is added per click

2) user clicks once, and a large box appears, then a second box appears inside it, then a third inside that one, and so forth until there isn't enough room for another box

In neither case does true recursion seem relevant; the visuals have led you astray.

I'll tackle number 2.

The general algorithm will probably look something like this:

```
function matryoshka() {
  while(true) {
    // create box and add to document
    // measure the box that was just added
    // if measurements suggest no more space inside, break
  }   
}
```

At this point, you just need to research the details of DOM measurement, and maybe google "matryoshka" to learn that they're those Russian nesting dolls.

But I think you're going to run into a problem: this approach assumes that the DOM is organized in a particular way (that boxes are nested inside each other), and that layout has been implemented such that each box naturally sizes itself as 80% of its parent container. Your current CSS does not do that, which means that fleshing out the JS stub will not get you all the way there.

Finally, I should point out that DOM operations are not instantaneous, with the consequence that if you measure the geometry of an element *immediately* after adding it, you will often get incorrect values. You may need to introduce a delay (which would actually lead to a recursive pattern), or simply handle the math via dead reckoning: you can get the viewport dimensions, you can track the number of boxes that have been created, and so you can theoretically do the limit-checking as a pure function that does not require interrogating the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

**Check this out (working snippet at end of post):**

I added a `window.onload` function, to make sure the element is loaded before adding the listener.

How it works:

```
function addListener(element) {

  element.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (this.childElementCount === 0 && this.offsetWidth >= 100 && 
    this.offsetHeight >= 100) appendBoxes(this);

  });
}
```

When the `window.onload` function is called, it adds a listener to the box currently on the screen:

```
addListener(document.querySelector('.loop-over'));
```

If the `eventListener` function is called, it first checks if the clicked element (`this`) has no children, so only the smallest box will generate a new box:

```
this.childElementCount === 0
```

Then it also checks if the element is big enough (here I chose a minimum of 100px*100px, but you can change that):

```
this.offsetWidth >= 100 && this.offsetHeight >= 100
```

If that is all true, it calls the function that generates the box (you could put it all in the anonymous function if you wanted..):

```
function appendBoxes(element) {

  element.append(element.cloneNode(true));
  addListener(element.firstChild);

}
```

First, a new element is created, and then, in `addListener(element.firstChild)`, the child gets a listener too.

**SNIPPET:**

```js
window.onload = function() {

  addListener(document.querySelector('.loop-over'));

}



function addListener(element) {

  element.addEventListener('click', function() {

    if (this.childElementCount === 0 && this.offsetWidth >= 100 && this.offsetHeight >= 100)
      appendBoxes(this);
    else if (this.offsetWidth < 100 || this.offsetHeight < 100) alert("stack limit reached!!");
  });
}

function appendBoxes(element) {

  element.append(element.cloneNode(true));
  addListener(element.firstChild);

}
```

```css
.modal {
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal loop-over"></div>
```

Comment: Hey, it works perfectly. My one final doubt, how do I get an alert when it reaches the minimum height and width because when I add else statement, it gives me an alert right after one click due to this.childElementCount === 0 statement?

Comment: @V.Spock Yea, `this.childElementCount === 0` checks if the clicked element has no children. So maybe try using an `else if` block with `(this.offsetWidth < 100 || this.offsetHeight < 100)` ? I'll add it in the snippet.